# How do you write a counter method to save space and time?

Tags: java, list, counter

I am working with interface *Multiset* which is then used by two different classes: *ArrayListMultiset* and *CounterMultiset*

The ArrayListMultiset simply uses the .add method to put something in the list. So in a loop like,

```
Multiset<String> set = new Multiset<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{ 
    set.add("Hello");
}
```

this will cause the program to add Hello to a list 10,000 times.

Next we have CounterMultiset. It stores a Pair object (another class that takes in `(T, Integer)`, where `T` is the String, "Hello" and `Integer` is the number of times it is trying to be added. I have written it like so:

```
public void add(Multiset<T> item) 
{
    if(!contains(item))
    {
        Pair newpair = new Pair(item, 0);
        pairs.add(newpair);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++)
    {
        if(pairs.get(i).getFirst() == item)
        {
            pairs.get(i).changeSecond();
        }
    }
}
```

changeSecond() increments the second number in the Object by 1 to show that the word Hello has tried to be added again.

My question is, is this an appropriate way to save space and time for a program? When would it be faster to use a Counter and when would it be faster to simply add "Hello" 10,000 times?

Comment: why not just do `set.add("Hello", 10000)`

Comment: What would it be faster for? What are the operations you're expecting? 
If you're using multisets like this, you're trading cpu cycles for memory. Usually, just plain storing it in memory is faster... unless you're expecting repeated calls of, say, the number of words, after adding a set.

Comment: @Kelvin Same idea, but still curious as to which one is better in which situation.

Comment: @KoosGadellaa Let's say I'm storing Hello a thousand times and that's it. I have run tests and seen that simply adding it without using a counter is faster. So, I guess my question is, is there any situation in which I'd rather use a counter? My thought process was that using a counter would be quicker if I were adding the same word over and over again, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: See Sergey Rybalkin's answer. The strings are interned, so it's only pushing around references. It will always be faster to add them without a counter. However, depending on how you use it afterwards, it might be acceptable to lose a little bit of performance adding it, if it gives you advantages later on.

Comment: It depends on the interface. For "pure" interfaces like Guava where the only kind of equality that applies is `equals` (e.g. `remove` is only certain to remove _some_ copy of duplicate items; there is no way to specify which one), the counter implementation is the only one that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`Hello` is an intern string in your code.

You will not have a copy of `Hello` for each element of `ArrayListMultiset`. You will have a reference to String Pool object.

What is faster for get/put (I assume) - depends on underlying data structures.